# How to find a folder size under s3 bucket NON RECURSIVE

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I tried recursive way to find folder size under de bucket that works pretty well, but doesn't satisfy the use case for large number of files/folder it takes too much time.
So do we have any SDK support or anything?

Comment: No. There is no other way.

Comment: An alternative option is to use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects and their sizes.